# var like variable outside methods

Tags: c#, methods, var

The title may not be so expecific, sorry for that. I'd like to know if there is a type of variable(or class or something) that works like the type "var" but outside a method, inside the class, I want to use it as a parameter like that:

```
public class ConfigParam
{
    string paramName;
    var paramValue;

    public ConfigParam(string name, var value)
    {
        paramName = name;
        paramValue = value;
    }

    public string ParamName
    {
        get { return paramName; }
        set { paramName = value; }
    }

    public var ParamValue
    {
        get { return paramValue; }
        set { paramValue = value; }
    }
}
```

but the "var" type don't work outside method. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `Object`...........?

Comment: You can't use `var` as a method parameter type. It has to known on compile time. How can I call this constructor then? `ConfigParam(string, string)` or `ConfigParam(string, DateTime)` or other types? One way can be use generics.

Comment: Oh, thanks, the "object" works fine. I actually haven't tested the "T" one, but I'm sure it might work to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `object`

```
public class ConfigParam
{
    string paramName;
    object paramValue;

    public ConfigParam(string name, object value)
    {
        paramName = name;
        paramValue = value;
    }

    public string ParamName
    {
        get { return paramName; }
        set { paramName = value; }
    }

    public object ParamValue
    {
        get { return paramValue; }
        set { paramValue = value; }
    }
}
```

No type safety, but it will be working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use generics:

```
public class ConfigParam<T>
{
    string paramName;
    T paramValue;

    public ConfigParam(string name, T value)
    {
        paramName = name;
        paramValue = value;
    }

    public string ParamName
    {
        get { return paramName; }
        set { paramName = value; }
    }

    public T ParamValue
    {
        get { return paramValue; }
        set { paramValue = value; }
    }
}
```

If you need to do more than store the type `T` you can apply [generic constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).